# replace last dot in a string with a dollar sign

Tags: java, regex, replace

I would like to replace the last dot in the following string with a dollar sign, how can I do that?

```
de.java_chess.javaChess.game.GameImpl.GameStatus
```

I would like to have `de.java_chess.javaChess.game.GameImpl$GameStatus` instead.

I am using the following line of code to do so:

```
invokedMeth = invokedMeth.replaceAll("(.*)\\.(\\d+)$","$1$$2");
```

However, this doesn't work and I end up with the same original string that I had as an input. How can I fix this?

Comment: The \\d+ in the regex matches a number, but you have none in your string. The dollar in the middle of the replacement has propably to be escaped. And last thing is that replaceAll replaces not only the last dot, but every dot in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this requirement, I would use a non-regex solution that can be easier to understand as well as more efficient.

```
StringBuilder invokedMethSb = new StringBuilder(invokedMeth);
invokedMethSb.setCharAt(invokedMethSb.lastIndexOf("."), '$');

invokedMeth = invokedMethSb.toString();  
/*de.java_chess.javaChess.game.GameImpl$GameStatus*/
```

[**StringBuilder**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) has some good utils for these operations, such as [`setCharAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char)).

---

As a personal opinion, I prefer the following one:

```
char[] invokedArray = invokedMeth.toCharArray();
invokedArray[invokedMeth.lastIndexOf(".")]='$';

invokedMeth = new String(invokedArray);
/*de.java_chess.javaChess.game.GameImpl$GameStatus*/
```

**Regex solution:**

You can use the [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `(?=([^.]*)$)` where `([^.]*)` matches any number of non-dot (i.e. `[^.]`) character and `$` asserts position at the end of a line. You can check [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vzutdl/1) for more explanation.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "de.java_chess.javaChess.game.GameImpl.GameStatus";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\.(?=([^.]*)$)", "\\$");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
de.java_chess.javaChess.game.GameImpl$GameStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

A proper regular expression can also help with this replacement:

```java
String withDot = "de.java_chess.javaChess.game.GameImpl.GameStatus";
 
String with$ = withDot.replaceFirst("(\\w+(\\.\\w+)*)(\\.(\\w+))", "$1\\$$4");
 
System.out.println(with$);
```

Output [online demo](https://ideone.com/P7O3gY):

```
de.java_chess.javaChess.game.GameImpl$GameStatus
```